# Combine two Observables running in different threads

Tags: rx-java

Here is what I want to achieve:

1. query the db and emit the items. This runs on db thread.
2. After step 1, call api to refresh and save new results into db, then emit the new results. This runs on network thread.

So my question is, how can I combine the two into one Observable and have the subscriber to update the ui in each onNext()? Here's my current code, which feel a bit anti-pattern:

```
public Observable<List<Expense>> call() {
                    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<List<Expense>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void call(final Subscriber<? super List<Expense>> subscriber) {
                            List<Expense> expenses = fromLocal();
                            subscriber.onNext(expenses);
                            GetExpensesJob getExpensesJob = job.get();
                            getExpensesJob.setPage(page).setCount(count);
                            if (expenses == null || expenses.size() == 0 || getExpensesJob.shouldRun()) {
                                getExpensesJob.run().doOnNext(new Action1<List<Expense>>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void call(List<Expense> expenses) {

                                        if (expenses != null) {

                                            .... save in db...
                                            subscriber.onNext(expenses);                                            
                                        }
                                    }
                                }).doOnError(new Action1<Throwable>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                                        subscriber.onError(throwable);
                                    }
                                }).subscribeOn(ApiModule.scheduler()).subscribe();

                            }
                        }
                    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())

                            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

                }
            },
            new Action2<ExpensesView, List<Expense>>() {
                @Override
                public void call(ExpensesView expensesView, List<Expense> response) {
                    expensesView.stopLoading();
                    expensesView.onData(response);
                }
            },
            new Action2<ExpensesView, Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void call(ExpensesView expensesView, Throwable throwable) {
                    expensesView.showError(throwable);
                }
```

Comment: if you found an answer, post it as an answer, and mark it as such. this way, the question is marked resolved

Comment: I have moved the answer from the start of the question (where it was confusing) to an answer below. I have removed the request for upvotes - please do not add this to your material! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*

I haven't received any answers but I figured out how to do this.  If this might help you,  the code would be like this:

```
Observervable dbObs = Observabe.create(...).subscribeOn(...);     
Observable  apiObs = Observable.create(...).subscribeOn(...);    
Observable.concat(dbObs,apiObs).subscribe(...)
```

The trick here is you need to call subscriber.onComplete from your observables otherwise the subsequent Observable won't get subscription.

Comment: `concat(..)` processes only one observable after another, but if you have sources that emit items constantly, you should consider using `mergeWith(..)` so that you won't wait to receive all items from the first observable to start receiving from second one.